# Django URL redirecting issue

Tags: python, django, url

i have a redirect url problem when the user complete editing his profile informations ,i want to redirect to the profile page , but it display to me 404 error 
this is My view.py file  :

```
def ProfileView(request, pk=None):
    prof = Profile.objects.all()
    if pk:
        pr = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        pr = request.user
    context= {
        'pro':prof,
        'profile':pr

    }

    return render(request,'profile.html',context)

def update_profile(request,id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=id)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None ,request.FILES or None,instance=profile)


    if request.method=='POST':
       if form.is_valid:
           form.save()
           return redirect(reverse('profile-detail'))
   context = {
       'form':form
   }
   return render(request,'profile_update.html',context)
```

thi is my url.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path ('',index),
    path ('events_details/<id>',events_details,name="events_details"),
    path ('evenements/',evenements,name="events"),
    path ('projets/',projets,name="project"),
    path ('project_detail/<id>/',project_detail,name="project-detail"),
    path ('create_post',create_post,name="create_post"),
    path ('project_detail/<id>/update_post',update_post,name="update_post"),
    path ('project_detail/<id>/delete_post',delete_post,name="delete_post"),
#------------------------------------------------------------
    path ('profile/',ProfileView,name="profile-detail"),
    path ('profile_update/<id>',update_profile,name="profile-update"),


    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))    
]
```

The  Error i got :

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile_update/
.
.
.
The current path, profile_update/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error page from Django (preferably with DEBUG=True in settings.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your url expects an **id** with the url (ie `localhost:8000/profile_update/12`), but when you are making a post request, you are not sending one.

So I am guessing you need to update the code like this:

```
def update_profile(request,id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=id)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None ,request.FILES or None,instance=profile)
    if request.method=='POST':
       if form.is_valid:
           form.save()
           return redirect(reverse('profile-detail'))
   context = {
       'form':form,
       'pk': id
   }
   return render(request,'profile_update.html',context)
```

And update the template as well:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url 'profile-update' pk %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the redirect line from

```
return redirect(reverse('profile-detail'))
```

to

```
return redirect('app-name:profile-detail')
```

where `app-name` is the name of your django app.

Comment: i tried this already , same result   :

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile_update/

Comment: i has no relation with the name of the view

Comment: Post the stacktrace when debug is enabled so we can have better insight.